# Apply Alternate CSS to all site collections via Powershell in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, powershell, css, style

I have a SharePoint 2013 environment where I want to apply a single Alternate CSS file across all site collections and subsites. I am using the following method. When I run this I receive a single error, the Alternate CSS is applied to all sites and subsites EXCEPT on the root site collection. Any ideas how I can get this to work for the root site collection as well?

```
$Webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://MyServer/"

$Sites = $Webapp.sites.url
foreach ($site in $sites)
{
  $web = Get-SPWeb $site
  $cssurl = "/SiteAssets/DevColorChange.css"
  $web.AlternateCssUrl = $cssurl
  $web.AllProperties["__InheritsAlternateCssUrl"] = $True
  $web.Update()
}
```

ERROR:

> Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Specified data type
>   does     not match the current data type of the property." At line:10
>   char:1
>   + $web.Update()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPInvalidPropertyException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-SPWebApplication "http://MyServer/" | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | % { $_.AlternateCssUrl = ($_.Site.Url + "/SiteAssets/DevColorChange.css");$_.Update() }
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case I have a single CSS file located at: http://MyServer/SiteAssets/DevColorChange.css 


When I run your command it does make the Alternate CSS changes across all site collections/subsites including the root, however on every site collect EXCEPT the root it points to: http://MyServer/sites/SITECOLLECTION/SiteAssets/DevColorChange.css


Instead of http://MyServer/SiteAssets/DevColorChange.css


Removing `$_.Site.Url +` from `$_.AlternateCssUrl = ($_.Site.Url + "/SiteAssets/DevColorChange.css")` Gives me the results I am looking for

Comment: True, your URL is a serverrelative URL already ;-)