# Remove Left Navigation and Edit Link Option from SharePoint Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, custom-masterpage, designer, style.css

I am seeking to apply Script or css to root SharePoint site which should get effected to all the site collections and remove Left Navigation and "Edit Links" option which exists on Top link bar.

Answer (score 2):

No need for MasterPage changes

You can load a CSS file as UserCustomAction for the whole Site Collection (or one Web)

- Use Chrome
- Install the SPEditor: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd?hl=en
- Open your site
- Press F12
- Select the SharePoint Tab
- enter the complete path to your CSS file
- set as SiteCollection scriptlink
- Your CSS file will now always be loaded early on

[image]

Note: Your CSS could be loaded **before** SharePoint CSS, so you need to set your [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) right on all selectors so they overrule the later loaded CSS files

This is also the best way to load any JS Library

Comment: Nice tool! Like it

Answer (score 0):

To remove left navigation, add below style into master page:

```
 #sideNavBox {display: none}
```

To remove edit links from top navigation, add below style into master page:

```
#DeltaTopNavigation .ms-core-listMenu-root .ms-listMenu-editLink {display: none;}
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: To add: you might want to deploy the style change via PowerShell if you are not using a general masterpage/stylesheet where the changes could be done conveniently. To do so, see https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176142/apply-alternate-css-to-all-site-collections-via-powershell-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Seeking for solution which should get apply from root site to all other sub sites

Comment: yes, you will need to add this style into site collection master page.If all subsites inherited this master page then it will automatically worked for all subsites.