# How to add reference to a custom css file in SharePoint online Master page

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

Can some one please tell me why this is not working, I m using SharePoint online 
On second line I m referring to the custom css.
[image]

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">  
    #DeltaPlaceHolderSearchArea {  
        display: none;  
    }  
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please double check the css path? If it's correct or not. I am assuming that you are using classic experience in sharepoint online site?

Comment: Dikesh, I have double checked it and attached the screenshot. Yes using classic mode

Comment: can you check it as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_catalogs/masterpage/Style Library/customcss.css" />`  or `<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Style Library/customcss.css%>" after="corev15.css" runat="server"/>`?

Comment: Hi Gautam, second option worked, thank you very much

Comment: Cool, have posted it as answer, please accept it by ticking the checkmark besides the answer ! You will get a learner badge as well, cheers , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. You can easily add a reference to a new css without editing the master page. There is a property on the web object called AlternateCSSUrl that can be set to ref your css. Use it instead. This will give you a start: [Setting AlternateCssUrl in all subsites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218255/setting-alternatecssurl-in-all-subsites/218258#218258)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can reference css files using `link` tags or using `SharePoint:CssRegistration` as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_catalogs/masterpage/Style Library/customcss.css" />
```

or

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Style Library/customcss.css%>" after="corev15.css" runat="server"/>
```

When you use `CssRegistration` along with the `~SiteCollection` token, SharePoint will convert it to the correct site collection URL and render it on the page.